# WP Plugin Contact Form 7 - Custom PHP function result to End User

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have been playing around with the Contact Form 7 for a few days.
What I am trying accomplish is the following

1) Setup up a form

2) When clicking submit I "enter" my custom php function where I have hooked one of these events

- add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', ...
- add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', ...
- add_action('wpcf7_mail_failed', ...

3) In this custom php function I want to do some handling of the data filled in by the user. Like calculations and such.

4) The result needs to go back to the user. I was thinking through a simple GET like www.mydomain.com/ResultPage/?result=FooBar
This way I can present it nicely. (the present page is working)

What I have succeeded with so far is the first 3 steps, but the fourth one I can't figure out.

I have tried all kinds of ways, like these two
* Changing the posted data (which did not have any effect)
* Doing a wp_redirect (which broke the form, it wouldn't "complete")

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't really make it work like above. I did it with AJAX instead.